# Regex: Match a pattern but exclude one case

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I want to include all strings starting from a to m.
This can be done using **[a-m]*** regex
but I don't want a case where the string starts with "*deal_string*". What is the regular expression for this?

Test cases:

```
assets/filename.ext           -> pass
deal_string/filename.ext      -> fail
deal_string.ext               -> fail
deal_string_1.ext             -> fail
deal_draft.txt                -> pass
assets_deal_string.txt        -> pass
bombay.txt                    -> pass
zombie.srt                    -> fail
some_deal_string.txt          -> fail
zobie_special_string.txt      -> fail
```

Comment: If you want to include all strings that start from `a` to `m` then how is it that all of the other cases pass? The only ones that should pass excluding `special_string` is `assets/filename.ext` and `bombay.txt`

Comment: @Yesuagg: In what language/tool are you doing this regex?

Comment: @hwnd: My bad. Updated the test cases.

Comment: @anubhava: Ruby on rails

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use  a **Negative Lookahead** here. If you want to match all strings that begin with `a` through `m` excluding the strings that begin with "deal_string", you can use:.

```
^(?!deal_string)[a-m].*$
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eD1oM8/2)